# Laravel & Eloquent : setTable() in relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the `setTable()` method on eloquent calls because I'm using tables like `INFO_MATCH_[group_id]` where `group_id` is specific to a group of users. The same applies to the table `INFO_[group_id]`. I can do a simple select statement like this:

```
$ad = new InfoMatch();
$ad->setTable('INFO_MATCH_'.Auth::user()->group_id);
$data = $ad->get();
```

This works fine. The `InfoMatch` model has a relationship defined like:

```
public function infoDetails() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Info::class, 'info_id', 'id');
}
```

When I try to make a call like:

```
        $ad = new InfoMatch();
        $ad->setTable('INFO_MATCH_'.Auth::user()->group_id);
        $data = $ad->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->with('infoDetails')->get();
```

it ends up with an error. Could you advise how to dynamically set the table name in the relationship function? Thanks.

Comment: "It ends up with an error". If you can show us the error, please...

Comment: It just returns NULL on the 'infoDetails' because the table INFO is empty. I need to look into the INFO_[group_id] table.ie if the group_id is T32QXKH45 I need to make a relation between the INFO_MATCH_ T32QXKH45 table and the INFO_T32QXKH45 tables.

Comment: And are you sure the problem is the name of the table? What you do looks good and shouldn't be a source of errors. By the way, "NULL" is not an error...

Comment: Well the Info model has a defined $table like $table = 'INFO' but I need to look into the INFO_T32QXKH45 table instead. I can't set the table name in the call to the ->with('infoDetails').

Comment: I see your problem... I'm convinced it is not the most beautiful solution, but maybe you can override the gettable() method of your Info model right before doing the call?

Answer (score 2):

just like this:

```
public function detail()
{
    return $this->myHasOne(Circle::class, 'group_id', 'group_id', 't_group_' . hashID($this->group_id, 20));
}

public function myHasOne($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null, $table)
{
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

    $instance = (new $related)->setTable($table);

    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

    return new HasOne($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable() . '.' . $foreignKey, $localKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what if you **fresh** the instance after get, before `where`

```
$ad = new InfoMatch();
$ad->setTable('INFO_MATCH_'.Auth::user()->group_id);

$ad->refresh();
$data = $ad->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->with('infoDetails')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with() is static, so you need to add a static method to set the table name, and override getTable:

```
protected static $globalTable = 'defaultName' ;

public function getTable() {
    return self::$globalTable ;
}
public static function setGlobalTable($table) {
    self::$globalTable = $table;
}
```

Then you call:

```
MyModel::setGlobalTable('table02') ;
```